# Sort table (List) based on value of resistors

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to sort a table of resistor values (third column), using Python 3, so that values are sorted properly based on the suffix (ie. K, M, etc.). Below is the table, it's a list of lists.

```
Thick Film                              0    .1W          -
Thick Film                              0    .125W        -
Trimmer                              100K    -            -
Thermistor             1206           10K    -            -
Thick Film                            10K    .25W        5%
Thin Film              0603           10K    .1W         1%
Trimmer                               10K    -            -
Thin Film                           17.4K    .125W       1%
Thick Film                             18    -            -
Thick Film             0805            1K    -           5%
Thick Film                             1K    -            -
Trimmer                               20K    -            -
Thick Film                            22K    .5W       0.5%
Thick Film             0805           270    -           1%
Thick Film                             2K    .25W         -
Thick Film                             2K    .125W       1%
Thin Film              0603            2K    .1W         1%
Thin Film              1206            2K    -         0.1%
Trimmer                                2K    -            -
Thin Film              0805          3.9K    -         0.5%
Thick Film                           4.7K    .125W       1%
Thick Film             0805           47k    .125W       5%
Thin Film                              50    .1W          -
Trimmer                               50K    -            -
Trimmer                                5K    -            -
Thick Film             0805         60.4K    .5W         1%
Thick Film             0805         71.5K    .5W         1%
Thin Film              0805            75    -         0.5%
Thick Film             0805           75K    .5W         1%
Thick Film                           8.06    .1W          -


part_list = [['Thick Film ', '0805', '47k', '.125W', '5%'], ['Thick Film ', '0805', '270', '-', '1%'], ['Thick Film ', '0805', '1K', '-', '5%'], ['Thick Film ', '0805', '60.4K', '.5W', '1%'], ['Thick Film ', '0805', '71.5K', '.5W', '1%'], ['Thick Film ', '0805', '75K', '.5W', '1%'], ['Thick Film ', '', '0', '.1W', '-'], ['Thick Film ', '', '8.06', '.1W', '-'], ['Thick Film ', '', '2K', '.25W', '-'], ['Thick Film ', '', '10K', '.25W', '5%'], ['Thick Film ', '', '0', '.125W', '-'], ['Thick Film ', '', '2K', '.125W', '1%'], ['Thick Film ', '', '4.7K', '.125W', '1%'], ['Thick Film ', '', '18', '-', '-'], ['Thick Film ', '', '1K', '-', '-'], ['Thick Film ', '', '22K', '.5W', '0.5%'], ['Thin Film ', '', '-', '-', '-'], ['Thin Film ', '0603', '10K', '.1W', '1%'], ['Thin Film ', '0603', '2K', '.1W', '1%'], ['Thin Film ', '0805', '3.9K', '-', '0.5%'], ['Thin Film ', '0805', '75', '-', '0.5%'], ['Thin Film ', '', '50', '.1W', '-'], ['Thin Film ', '', '17.4K', '.125W', '1%'], ['Thin Film ', '1206', '2K', '-', '0.1%'], ['Trimmer ', '', '100K', '-', '-'], ['Trimmer ', '', '10K', '-', '-'], ['Trimmer ', '', '20K', '-', '-'], ['Trimmer ', '', '2K', '-', '-'], ['Trimmer ', '', '50K', '-', '-'], ['Trimmer ', '', '5K', '-', '-'], ['Trimmer ', '', '-', '-', '-']]

from operator import itemgetter

sorted_list = sorted(part_list, key=itemgetter(2))
for part in sorted_list:
    print("{:<15s}{:>12s}{:>14s}    {:<6s}{:>8s}".format(part[0], part[1], part[2], part[3], part[4], '\n'))
```

The table needs to be sorted by the third column so that the values with 'K' or 'M' are numerically sorted at the bottom and the values without 'K' are numerically sorted above the values with 'K'. For example like this table.

```
Thick Film                              0    .1W          -
Thick Film                              0    .125W        -
Thick Film                           8.06    .1W          -
Thick Film                             18    -            -
Thin Film                              50    .1W          -
Thick Film             0805           270    -           1%
Thick Film             0805            1K    -           5%
Thin Film              0805          3.9K    -         0.5%
Thick Film                            10K    .25W        5%
Thick Film             0805         60.4K    .5W         1%
Thick Film             0805         71.5K    .5W         1%
Trimmer                              100K    -            -
Thick Film                            10M    .25W        5%
Thick Film                            39M    .125W       10%
```

EDIT: I just noticed the 3rd column in the code sample list has " ohms" in it, disregard that. It should just a numerical value without a suffix, or with a "K" or "M" suffix after the number.

EDIT 2: just fixed above with correct list.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the formatting, the code sample below the table needs to be separate. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

part_list = [['Thick Film ', '', '0 ohms', '.1W', '-'], ['Thick Film ', '', '0 ohms', '.125W', '-'], ['Thick Film ', '0805', '1.0K ohms', '-', '5%'], ['Trimmer ', '', '100K ohms', '-', '-'], ['Thermistor', '1206', '10K ohms', '-', '-'], ['Thick Film ', '', '10K ohms', '.25W', '5%'], ['Thin Film ', '0603', '10K ohms', '.1W', '1%'], ['Trimmer ', '', '10K ohms', '-', '-'], ['Thin Film ', '', '17.4K ohms', '.125W', '1%'], ['Thick Film ', '', '18 ohms', '-', '-'], ['Thick Film ', '', '1K ohms', '-', '-'], ['Thick Film ', '', '2.0K ohms', '.25W', '-'], ['Trimmer ', '', '20K ohms', '-', '-'], ['Thick Film ', '', '22K ohms', '.5W', '0.5%'], ['Thick Film ', '0805', '270 ohms', '-', '1%'], ['Thick Film ', '', '2K ohms', '.125W', '1%'], ['Thin Film ', '0603', '2K ohms', '.1W', '1%'], ['Thin Film ', '1206', '2K ohms', '-', '0.1%'], ['Trimmer ', '', '2K ohms', '-', '-'], ['Thin Film ', '0805', '3.9K ohms', '-', '0.5%'], ['Thick Film ', '', '4.7K ohms', '.125W', '1%'], ['Thick Film ', '0805', '47k ohms', '.125W', '5%'], ['Thin Film ', '', '50 ohms', '.1W', '-'], ['Trimmer ', '', '50K ohms', '-', '-'], ['Trimmer ', '', '5K ohms', '-', '-'], ['Thick Film ', '0805', '60.4K ohms', '.5W', '1%'], ['Thick Film ', '0805', '71.5K ohms', '.5W', '1%'], ['Thin Film ', '0805', '75 ohms', '-', '0.5%'], ['Thick Film ', '0805', '75K ohms', '.5W', '1%'], ['Thick Film ', '', '8.06 ohms', '.1W', '-']]

def key_fn(k):
    num, km = re.findall(r'(-?\d+\.?\d*)(k|m)?', k[2], re.I)[0]
    return float(num) * {'':1, 'K':1_000, 'M':1_000_000}[str.upper(km)]

for v in sorted(part_list, key=key_fn):
    print(('{:<15}'*5).format(*v))
```

Prints:

```
Thick Film                    0 ohms         .1W            -              
Thick Film                    0 ohms         .125W          -              
Thick Film                    8.06 ohms      .1W            -              
Thick Film                    18 ohms        -              -              
Thin Film                     50 ohms        .1W            -              
Thin Film      0805           75 ohms        -              0.5%           
Thick Film     0805           270 ohms       -              1%             
Thick Film     0805           1.0K ohms      -              5%             
Thick Film                    1K ohms        -              -              
Thick Film                    2.0K ohms      .25W           -              
Thick Film                    2K ohms        .125W          1%             
Thin Film      0603           2K ohms        .1W            1%             
Thin Film      1206           2K ohms        -              0.1%           
Trimmer                       2K ohms        -              -              
Thin Film      0805           3.9K ohms      -              0.5%           
Thick Film                    4.7K ohms      .125W          1%             
Trimmer                       5K ohms        -              -              
Thermistor     1206           10K ohms       -              -              
Thick Film                    10K ohms       .25W           5%             
Thin Film      0603           10K ohms       .1W            1%             
Trimmer                       10K ohms       -              -              
Thin Film                     17.4K ohms     .125W          1%             
Trimmer                       20K ohms       -              -              
Thick Film                    22K ohms       .5W            0.5%           
Thick Film     0805           47k ohms       .125W          5%             
Trimmer                       50K ohms       -              -              
Thick Film     0805           60.4K ohms     .5W            1%             
Thick Film     0805           71.5K ohms     .5W            1%             
Thick Film     0805           75K ohms       .5W            1%             
Trimmer                       100K ohms      -              -
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej! Getting IndexError: list index out of range : num, km = re.findall(r'(\d+\.?\d*)(k|m)?', k[2], re.I)[0]   Otherwise I like the simplicity!

Comment: ok, I see in the data list there are 4 items with '-' because the value is unknown. I still need those rows, what value can I use to represent unknown so it will work with your code? Zero is a valid value, so I can't use that. EDIT: Maybe a '.' ?

Comment: @sdproto you can represent them with `-1` for example. Then these items will be put first. I edited the regexp to accept negative values.

Comment: Tried -1 but still get error:     num, km = re.findall(r'(\d+\.?\d*)(k|m)?', k[2], re.I)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: @sdproto Try `num, km = re.findall(r'(-?\d+\.?\d*)(k|m)?', k[2], re.I)[0]` I updated my answer with it.

Comment: Thanks Andrej, that works! Really appreciate your help!